# Bind array from model to knockout observable array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout-2.0

I have a list of string in my MVC controller:

```
fullCourse = new List<string>();
```

I want to bind it to `<select>` so I can submit the selected item to another action method in the same controller

```
<select data-bind="options:info, optionsCaption:'Choose',optionsText:'name', value:chosenInfo "></select>
```

I make a button to fill the select

```
<input type="button" data-bind="fillSelect " value="Clik" />
```

I try to bind it to an observable array like this:

```
this.fillSelect = function myFunction() {
        for ( i = 0; i < @Model.fullCourse.Count; i++) {
             this.info.push({name:@Model.fullCourse[i]);
        }
};

this.info = ko.observableArray([]);
```

The problem is syntax error:

> i is undefined in this scope

```
this.info.push({name:@Model.fullCourse[i]);
```

I am afraid that I'm doing it the wrong way.

Is there an easier way? Or could my method work?

Answer (score 0):

You need `var i`, i.e.:

```
for (var i = 0; i < @Model.fullCourse.Count; i++) {
```

Comment: the problem isn't in the loop for statement, i is work except when I use it in: @Model.fullCourse[i]

Comment: *You have not defined `i`*. That is your problem. Perhaps, try the solution before you argue about it?